# FFMPEG Bit Rate as 16Bit for Audio Conversion

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, file-conversion

I am using FFMPEG Audio Converter to convert the file format. At Present it bit rate is 176.4 kbit/s, so it file size to big.

I want to convert it as possible at low bit rate but unable to find any solution.

I use below command line to convert the file

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "Audio Input FilePath" "Audio Output FilePath"
```

Comment: Paste the full output of `ffmpeg -i input.wav `

Comment: Just to clarify, you want 16 Kbit per second, not 16-bit PCM samples, correct?

Comment: I only need to reduce the size of file . so i think when i reduce bit then it may reduce the size

Answer (score 2):

You can define with `-b:a` the target bitrate so try for example:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "Audio Input FilePath" -b:a 64k "Audio Output FilePath"
```

Comment: still the same size and bit rate : 176

Comment: try to add `-bufsize 64k` I thought that would be optional

Comment: If that won't work try `ffmpeg input.wav -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 9 output.mp3`

Comment: now, bit rate set as 128.0 but size increased by 14 MB. original file size is 807 kb

Comment: yes i am using "ffmpeg input.wav -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 9 output.mp3" this command and convert into WAV format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131323/discussion-between-mitesh-machhi-and-rekire).